# ACF checkbox meta query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

The below isn't working, can't see why. `is_focus_product` is a True/False ACF field

```
$ls = get_posts([
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'is_focus_product', 'value' => 1, 'compare' => '='
        ]
    ]
]);
// array(0){}
```

However this returns as expected...

```
var_dump(get_field('is_focus_product', 36));
// bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but IMO it's a bullshit WordPress flaw, it shouldn't be restricted to a certain post type because you should have the freedom (in this case anyway, I reckon there are billions of similar use cases) to filter as necessary (they are ALL posts after all...).

You need the post type, so...

```
$ls = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'focus_product', 'value' => '1', 'compare' => '='
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: `post_type` defaults to `post`. if you need all posts types, you need to set it to `any`. although that would also query attachments, revisions, (woocommerce product variations..) etc.. so.. an array `['post', 'product']` might be the proper solution to your needs

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use query to get posts:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'products',
    'posts_per_page'  => 4,
    'meta_key'      => 'focus_product',
    'meta_value'    => 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks but 1 -> as I said in my own solution, filtering posts by post_type is not always appropriate (in my case it's for a "featured" post which should be from any post type at all); and 2 -> with a single `meta_key/meta_value` you severely limit your ability to filter further, hence meta_query array.